# How to supply hardcoded multiline content in h:inputTextarea

Tags: jsf-2, textarea

In HTML I can do:

```
<textarea>
line 1
line 2
line 3
</textarea>
```

However, the same thing doesn't work with the JSF `<h:inputTextarea>`, as I have to specify the `value` attribute instead of the body. Is there a way that I can specify a multiline value? Ideally I would like to be able to do it as seamlessly as in HTML, ie with no `\n` and actually putting it onto multiple lines, for easy readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
<h:outputFormat escape="false" value="Line 1<br/>Line 2" />
```

Which would render:

Line 1

Line 2

**Note**:The escape="false" means you can embed html, like lists etc...

or else we can even try like this:

Alternatively you could set readonly to true on the inputTextArea and set the rows attribute.

I Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The thing is, I want the text to be editable, and I want it to be part of the inputTextarea, so that it can be submitted to the faces servlet along with any other input. I'm not sure that your solutions support that?

Comment: then just take readOnly attribute as false Simple...!!! so from then even that will be editable

Comment: I Want to know the exact reason of judging me that i am not familiar about JSF at all.Its not at all fair and u r not supposed to make comments on other's Knowledge. Mind it @BalusC even though if u have gud reputation it is just only upto you I won't care it at all

Comment: @BalusC who r u to judge me you are not any BOSS of SO and am not your student or slave JUST BE IN YOUR LIMITS

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find a way to include the textarea content directly into the .xhtml, while keeping the content on several lines. There's probably a way with some javascript by using a different tag and then copying it in or something, but I wanted to keep it fairly clean.

What I ended up doing was using the value attribute of h:inputTextarea and I populated it from my managedBean. I created text files of the content I wanted (they were quite big files) and loaded them into the managedBean property using a FileReader. When you assign them to the value of the h:inputTextArea, the \n etc are respected, so that it gives you the identical effect to if you had hardcoded the text into the .xhtml between textarea tags.

Comment: That's also the way you're actually supposed to use. Otherwise the whole `<h:inputTextarea>` is pointless and you could just get away with using `<textarea>`. JSF also supports emitting plain HTML, you know.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I guess I could just have included an HTML textarea as part of the form. Trying to learn JSF at the moment, so I guess perhaps I'm trying too hard to make everything JSF :-) Thanks for your help.